# Windows10で音声合成を追加できない

Tags: windows-10

ネットを参考に、いろいろ試したのですがすべて失敗しました。

ネットを参照した次のスクリプト

```
var voiceObj = new ActiveXObject("Sapi.SpVoice");
var voices = voiceObj.GetVoices();
var i,n=voices.Count;
var v; //VoiceObj.Voice
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    dprint("Item "+i);
    var v=voices.Item(i);
    dprint(v.GetDescription());
}

function dprint(s) {
    WScript.Stdout.WriteLine( s );
}
```

を実行すると、以下の結果です。

```
Item 0
Microsoft Haruka Desktop - Japanese
Item 1
Microsoft Zira Desktop - English (United States)
Item 2
Microsoft David Desktop - English (United States)
```

これを増やすために、例えば中国語、次をインストールしました。

SpeechPlatformRuntime 
MSSpeech_TTS_zh-CN_HuiHui

しかし失敗しました。

MSSpeech_TTS_zh-CN_HuiHuiについてはV11とV10.1の両方とも結果は同じでした。

なお、"プログラムと機能"にて、インストールされていることは確認しました。

どうすればいいのでしょうか。
なお、ネットでよく見られる音声認識には興味ありません。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　著作権の問題があるため、他のサイトのコードを引用した場合は、引用元の情報を記載してください。

Comment: ここでは、[Microsoft Speech API (SAPI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ee125663(v=VS.85).aspx) を JavaScript + ActiveX で利用されているのでしょうか？　第三者が問題を再現できるように、[確認可能な方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を説明してくださればと思います。

Comment: SpeechPlatformRuntime.msiをインストールします。32bitと64bit用両方です。

Comment: 次にMSSpeech_TTS_zh-CN_HuiHui.msiをインストールします。その後、"プログラムと機能"でインストールされていることを確認しました。しかし当該スクリプトでHuiHuiが見えません。なお、ずいぶん前ですがWindowsXPでは当時の方法で成功しました（具体的な手順は覚えていません）。

Comment: コメントは後から来た方が読みづらいので、質問文に追記して頂けますか？　「編集」から追記できます。